# Categorizing and printing values in predefined lists

Tags: php

I need to sort the data into different columns together based on a defined lists. (instead of echoing them separately). 
As shown in the example below, ten different columns from mysql table containing list of mixed letters.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>A,K,L</th> 
<th>X,O,Z</th> 
</tr>

 <?php    
  include ("dbconfig.php");
  $sql = "SELECT Stat1, Stat2, Stat3, Stat4, Stat5, Stat6, Stat7, Stat8, Stat9, Stat10 FROM Stats";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

The expected output would be like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrs7v.jpg)

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: loop through the result and columns, add the values to a new array if they match (array_reduce might be helpful). Please show what you have tried!

Comment: Please be more specific. What is held in the stat1, sta2.... columns. Is it one letter or multiple letters.

Comment: My php is knowledge is pretty basic. if each column was assigned with a specific value, I could do this. It is not like that. I can do this with excel, and upload the data to mysql and use it that way. If it's not a complicated question, and I can get answer, I'd like to use it a direct solution.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Each mysql column (Stat..) has a letter. It can be any letter. Each stat's assigned with on letter only.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php this class maybe usefull to make a clean solution to this problem, in particular you should give an eye on *sort method of that class.

Comment: @Pr DP, thanks. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snipped should do what you want - if I understood correctly. See inline comments for explanations!

```
<?php
// defining your 2 categories
$cat[1] = ["A","K","L"];
$cat[2] = ["X","O","Z"];

// mocking input data (but only 4 columns and 4 rows...)
$input = [
   ["Stat1"=>"A", "Stat2"=>"K", "Stat3"=>"Y","Stat4"=>"N"],
   ["Stat1"=>"X", "Stat2"=>"B", "Stat3"=>"K","Stat4"=>"M"],
   ["Stat1"=>"A", "Stat2"=>"K", "Stat3"=>"L","Stat4"=>"O"]
];


foreach($input as $row) {  // this will be your while($row = mysqli_fetch*) {

    // we could put the following into a loop (if categories should be dynamic)
    $columns[1] = array_filter($row, function($col) use ($cat) {
        if(in_array($col, $cat[1])) { // if the value is in category 1, add it
            return true;
        }
    });
    $columns[2] = array_filter($row, function($col) use ($cat) {
        if(in_array($col, $cat[2])) { // if the value is in category 2, add it
            return true;
        }
    });
    $output[] = $columns;  // add the 2 columns to the output as new row
}

// the actual output of the categorized data:
$table = <<<EOT
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>A,K,L</th> 
<th>X,O,Z</th> 
</tr>
EOT;

foreach($output as $row) {
    $table.="<tr>";
    foreach($row as $column) {
        $table .="<td>";
        $values = implode(",",$column);
        $table .= $values;
        $table .="</td>";
    }
    $table.="</tr>";
}
$table.="</table>";
echo $table;

// OUTPUT:
A,K,L   X,O,Z
-------------
A,K 
K       X
A,K,L   O
```

The docs for relevant functions used: [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. It works in the example. I just have one question, how should I define $input variable so it can extract the data in that format?

Comment: $input is what comes from your database. You won't have that variable, it's just here in this example to mock the database input. See my comment in line `foreach($input as $row)`!